# How to make a play and pause button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I am trying to make a play and pause button

**HTML:**

```
<img id="change" src="../play button.png" width="100" height="100" /><script src="../jquery.js"></script>
<div id ="video">
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('#change').click(function () {
    $('#video').html('<iframe width="0" height="0" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/....?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
});

$(function() {
  $('#change').click(function(){
    $("#change").attr('src',"../pause button.png");
  });
});
```

At the moment when you click on the play button it changes to a pause button `img`. And open a youtube video that opens hidden so that you can just hear the audio. I am looking to then; when you click the second time remove the `html` for the youtube video (So that it stops playing [or if you are feeling helpful you can help me find a way to make the video pause]) and then put the play button `img` back?

Comment: You'd probably be better off using the youtube javascript API if you want more control over the video than just putting it on the page.

Comment: Have you checked out the [YouTube Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference)?

Comment: I would rather do it myself.

Comment: I just implemented the youtube JS API yesterday. It's not really hard to do unless you think for some reason a huge service like youtube would support mobile devices... idiots

Comment: If you're going to do it yourself, you're going to have to somehow know how progressed the video is if you want to be able to make it continue where it was when you stopped it. good luck with that.

Comment: @KevinB Okay. Do you know how I would go about removing the html that I previously added?

Comment: Well yeah, that's easy. `$(theelement).remove()` or `$(theelement).detach()`. When you re-attach the video, it will start from the beginning again and will have to be re-downloaded.

Comment: @KevinB I know you can do`$(theelement).remove()` but then if you click the video id in the question it will just remove the element? I want it to be like a switch?

Comment: you could use detatch and then just re-append it back, but it's no different from using .remove and then .html.